# How to write Control Characters

Tags: xml

I have seen:

> Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 25))

exception in our logs. I wanted to create those control characters and put in xml. I have tried in notepad++, but that doesn't seem to be control characters. How can I create/write such control characters so that I can add it in my xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert control characters in CDATA section as follows

```
<![CDATA[&#25;]]>
```